# Does vector know to reserve first when initializing by a pair of iterators?

Tags: c++, stl

Consider the following code.

```
struct MyData{
    MyData(const BYTE* pData, size_t uSize) 
        : bucket_(pData, pData + uSize) 
    {}     
    std::vector<BYTE> bucket_;
};
```

Does my `bucket_` do the `reserve` first when initializing from a pair of iterators?  Something like `vec.reserve(std::distance(begIter, endIter))`.

Or it just simply perform a serious of `push_back` or `back_inserter_iterator::operator=` ?

If it does not, I may need to initialize it with `uSize` of 0 then do the `memcpy_s` in constructor block.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Does my `bucket_` do the `reserve` first when initializing from a pair of iterators?

Yes, it does in effect.

Standard draft:

> Complexity: Makes only N calls to the copy constructor of T (where N is the distance between first and last) and **no reallocations** if iterators first and last are of forward, bidirectional, or random access categories. It makes order N calls to the copy constructor of T and order log(N) reallocations if they are just input iterators.

(Pointers are random access iterators)

Comment: So it is mandated to do 2 passes if they are forward or bidirectional (one for distance, another for allocation).  In some corner cases (where iteration is far slower than copying resulting data), manual one at a time insert could be faster.

Comment: @Yakk: Probably; all of the standard library algorithms are likely to be implemented under the assumption that iteration is relatively cheap, so that rolling your own alternative may well be faster when that isn't true.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's guaranteed that there will be no reallocations, because pointers are RandomAccessIterators. [vector.cons/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector#cons-9)

> ```
> template <class InputIterator>
> vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const Allocator& = Allocator());
> ```
>
> *Effects:* Constructs a vector equal to the range `[first, last)`, using the specified allocator.
>
> *Complexity:* Makes only `N` calls to the copy constructor of `T` (where `N` is the distance between `first` and `last`) and **no
>   reallocations if iterators first and last are of forward,
>   bidirectional, or random access categories**. It makes order `N` calls
>   to the copy constructor of `T` and order `log(N)` reallocations if
>   they are just input iterators.